# ASP.NET web.config restrict access

Tags: asp.net, web-config

So,

Not done anything in ASP.NET in a long time, I'm restricting a specific page if the user isn't logged in. I've done this a thousand times and have no idea why it's not working.

Root:

file: web.config.

```
  <configuration>
     <system.web>
         <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
           <authentication mode="Forms">
             <forms loginUrl="restricted.aspx"/>
         </authentication>
       </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

In the folder containing restricted file:
 file: web2.config

```
<configuration>
     <system.web>
       <authorization>
         <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>`
```

Any idea's what I'm missing?

Cheers.

Comment: Could it possible had something to do with the extra `\`` character at the end of `web2.config`?